# Knockout foreach won't show anything

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm new at knockout, and when I want to use the foreach I only get 1 empty line of nothing, while there are 2 objects in my array?

This is my HTML code

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: lijst">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: naam"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: aantal"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

function Product(naam, aantal) {
    var self = this;
    self.naam = naam;
    self.aantal = aantal;
}

function komaan() {
    var self = this;
    self.lijst = ko.observableArray([
        new Product("Flesje Tonic", 6),
        new Product("Gin", 6)
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new komaan());
```

Comment: Any error on your console ?

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/49/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your knockout js library is not loaded properly.

Here is online example with your code that works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/wyeegtaL/1/

```
function Product(naam, aantal) {
    var self = this;
    self.naam = naam;
    self.aantal = aantal;
}

function komaan() {
    var self = this;
    self.lijst = ko.observableArray([
        new Product("Flesje Tonic", 6),
        new Product("Gin", 6)
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new komaan());
```

Comment: Yes I see it, there was a letter wrong with the reference that I overlooked thanks!